# Sending Email with Python Win32Com.Client Send Error

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com

I have my script to send out messages on Outlook via Python win32com.client. I can create the email and format my body but when I try to do `newmail.Send()`

I am getting an error I cannot figure out.

Below is my code along with the error:

```
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "Subject"
newMail.Body = "Actualemail"
newMail.To = "test@test.com"
newMail.Send()
```

I get the follow error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#105>", line 1, in <module>
    newMail.Send()
  File "<COMObject CreateItem>", line 2, in Send
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147467260, 'Operation aborted', None, None)
```

Anyone ever deal with this? Everything else works but the send function

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. For some reason when I displayed the email and then sent it got it working.

Comment: Maybe its the Namespace? Try replacing the obj with this:
`win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")`

Answer (score 0):

*On*

> ```
> newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
> ```

*Use the [type value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.OlItemType) instead of the [type name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.OlItemType)*

*Example*

> ```
> newMail = obj.CreateItem(0)
> ```