# Send outlook email using python

Tags: python, email, outlook, automation, win32com

I want to send outlook email via python and I found below script

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch, constants
const=win32com.client.constants
olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "I AM SUBJECT!!"
newMail.BodyFormat = 2 
newMail.HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the <span style='color:red'>message</span> text here.</BODY></HTML>"
newMail.To = "my_email@email.com"
newMail.display()
newMail.Send()
```

Everything works fine untill **newMail.Send()**, it gives this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-46-7e8e370e48a8>", line 1, in <module>
    newMail.Send()
File "<COMObject CreateItem>", line 2, in Send
com_error: (-2147467260, 'Operation aborted', None, None)
```

Comment: Try the solutions mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59365331/sending-email-with-python-win32com-client-send-error or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807942/sending-an-email-through-python. Neither has an accepted answer, but at least it'll give you something to try (which is a great thing to do before asking on SO).

Comment: Hey Manny, thanks for suggestions  but still I could not find any solution that works for this problem

Comment: Add time.sleep(2) before send

Answer (score 1):

You need to either display the message, or send it, but not both  - your code displays the message, and then immediately sends it.